# When converting real samples to complex, how much energy does the signal lose?

Tags: sampling, complex

Assertion:  When converting real samples to complex, the resulting complex vector will have half the energy of the original real vector. Simulation in Python tells me this is true.  However, my proof is showing that the result is 1/4 instead.  Where's the flaw?

Start with the energy in a vector of real samples (including signal and/or noise) and apply Parseval’s Relation:

$$E_x=P_x\tau=\frac{\tau}{N}\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}\left|x\left[n\right]\right|^2=\frac{1}{f_s}\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}{\left|X\left(e^{j\omega}\right)\right|^2d\omega}$$

Because x is real, it’s spectrum $X\left(e^{j\omega}\right)$ must be conjugate symmetric.  This means that one half of the sampled energy must be in each of the positive and negative frequency components.

$$E_x=\frac{1}{2\pi f_s}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}{\left|X\left(e^{j\omega}\right)\right|^2d\omega}=2\frac{1}{2\pi f_s}\int_{0}^{\pi}{\left|X\left(e^{j\omega}\right)\right|^2d\omega}$$

Upon conversion to complex, since we simply shift the spectrum by $\frac{\pi}{2}$ this becomes:

$$E_x=\frac{1}{\pi f_s}\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}{\left|X\left(e^{j\left(\omega+\frac{\pi}{2}\right)}\right)\right|^2d\omega}$$

After we low-pass filter, the filtered spectrum $X_f\left(e^{j\omega}\right)=0$ for all $|\omega|>\frac{\pi}{2}$

$$X_f\left(e^{j\omega}\right)=\Big\lbrace\substack{X\left(e^{j\left(ω+\frac{\pi}{2}\right)}\right),\ |\omega|\leq\frac{\pi}{2}\\\\0,\ |\omega|>\frac{\pi}{2}}$$

and the energy in the filtered signal is now half of what it was prior to the complex conversion:

$$E_f=\frac{1}{2\pi f_s}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}{\left|X_f\left(e^{j\omega}\right)\right|^2d\omega}=\frac{1}{2\pi f_s}\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}{\left|X\left(e^{j\left(\omega+\frac{\pi}{2}\right)}\right)\right|^2d\omega}=\frac{E_x}{2}$$

Once we down-sample by a factor of two, the spectrum becomes:

$$X_d\left(e^{j\omega}\right)=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=0}^{1}{X_f\left(e^{j\left(\frac{\omega}{2}-\pi i\right)}\right)}=\frac{1}{2}\left(X_f\left(e^{j\frac{\omega}{2}}\right)+X_f\left(e^{j\left(\frac{\omega}{2}-\pi\right)}\right)\right)$$

The second term clearly equals zero for all $\omega$.  Therefore,

$X_d\left(e^{j\omega}\right)=\frac{1}{2}X_f\left(e^{j\frac{\omega}{2}}\right)$
for all $\omega$.  It follows that the energy in the filtered and down-sampled (decimated) signal is:

$$E_d=\frac{1}{2\pi\frac{f_s}{2}}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}{\left|\frac{1}{2}X_f\left(e^{j\frac{\omega}{2}}\right)\right|^2d\omega}=\frac{1}{4\pi f_s}\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}{\left|X_f\left(e^{j\omega}\right)\right|^2d\omega}=\frac{1}{4\pi f_s}\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}{\left|X\left(e^{j\left(\omega+\frac{\pi}{2}\right)}\right)\right|^2d\omega}=\frac{E_x}{4}$$

But, I don't think that last equation is actually correct.  Can anyone find the error?

Comment: When you mean converting to complex, do you mean making the signal analytic? If you do, do a signal power calculation instead with the initial real signal being a cosine, then make it analytic and do the same. What do you see?

Comment: I'm dealing exclusively with a sampled signal.

Comment: @JonathanWilliams: you really need to define exactly what you mean by "converting to complex". There are dozens of ways to convert real to complex and most of them do NOT conserve energy in the way you assert. Apparently you do some shifting and low-pass filtering but the exact procedure is unclear. Most people would indeed interpret "real to complex" as generating an analytic signal, but I don't think this is what you are doing here.

Comment: @JonathanWilliams I understand that you're dealing with sampled signals, but aside from aliasing issues and scaling, the continuous-time analysis will give you insight into the answer.

Comment: Yes, I am creating an analytic signal, or one can also say that I'm creating the sampled version of the complex envelope of the real signal.

Comment: @Envidia By Euler's equation, $cos\left(\omega t\right)=\frac{e^{j\omega t}+e^{-j\omega t}}{2}$  
Naturally, the average power of the cosine is the square of the rms voltage, $P_{cos}=\frac{1}{2}$.  If I create the complex signal as $e^{j\omega t}$, I get a power of $1$.  If I create the complex signal as $\frac{e^{j\omega t}}{2}$, however, I get a power of $\frac{1}{4}$.  So, that factor of two is insidious.

Comment: @Envidia But, what I'm talking about is starting with a real signal and then converting it to complex (analytic).  That means that the negative frequencies have to be eliminated, the signal spectrum has to be shifted to baseband, and then the signal has to be decimated.